# Set values in pandas series to a random value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series, and I'd like to set all the values that are 0 to a random number between 100 and 1000. Is there a direct way of doing that? I've only seen a roundabout way like so:

```
nums = np.random.choice(range(100, 1100), size = 924)

df.loc[df['Target']==0] = nums
```

The error I get back here is "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable".

Size is 924 because I know that's how many values I want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the column as well. Switch the last line to

`df.loc[df['Target']==0, 'Target'] = nums`

Answer (score 1):

Would row by row suffice?

```
import random
df.Target = df.Target.apply(lambda x: random.randint(1, 1000) if x == 0 else x)
```

If the row's value in Target is `0`, then generate a random number, else just return what's already there.